# UTC gives wrong time?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic, date

When I do this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

And I chose "none of the above" then "UTC", the time changes from Eastern to . . . GMT/London? UTC should be 4 hours ahead of me, not five. I had this working on my other computer, but on my new box (U15.04 Gnome Classic), I'm not getting UTC, instead I get UTC plus an extra hour, as if it's London's time (daylight savings). Or my computer thinks it's in Central Time?

Basically, I want my system to think it's running UTC time (Eastern + 4 hours) and display in the "Indicator Applet Complete" the UTC time with ISO-8601 format:

```
date +%Y-%m-%dT%T
```

Comment: Well, a reboot solved the UTC sync problem, but how do I permanently reformat the date-time display?

Answer (score 0):

So, after following many bad leads, I finally found this:

```
> gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 'custom'
```

then

```
> gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

I'm sure

```
%Y-%m-%dT%T
```

does the same thing.